# Efficient way to make collapsible sidebar to remember clicked options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I've made a collapsible sidemenu that has many options that go into many levels. I want it so that when a user clicks on tons of different options and then finally navigates to a separate page, the options the user clicked will be remembered and will stay up.

I'm asking to get opinions on the best method of doing this. As of right now, I know of three methods that could work:

1. jQuery cookies
2. jQuery local storage
3. extract url, and determine which pages are open (though this one will not remember if the user picked other options)

Are there any others that I could use? Is going server-side or client-side best for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this with anchor tag `<a>`:

```
a:visited {
  //your css here
}
```

You can have anchor tag inside `li` tag or `div` tag in your side-menu items, and have different styles for visited and unvisited items. Each `<a>` will correspond to a URL and it will automatically remember which one is visited.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't understand how I can determine which div's, li's, etc. that I should be showing and hiding with just a :visited anchor. All this does is determine if you've been to it before or not, right?